# Canceling DataAdapter.Fill()

Tags: c#, ado.net

Scenario:
We have a DataGridView which is attached to DataAdapter (datatable), we load the data in datatable using (adapter.fill(query, datatable)) in a separate thread (using delegate and beginInvoke) and once the data is loaded we attached that datatable to datagridview (in the main thread)

Is there a way we can check if fill() is still executing and cancel it.

Real scenario:
User click on the user name and corresponding data is loaded in the datagrid. Sometime, user is impatient and click on the another user (here I want to cancel the previous fill and start a new fill)

UPDATE:
We keep two DataApdaters (and two DataTables) and we attach one datatable to datagridview and start loading data to another datatable asynchronously. When data is loaded we simply bind the datagridview to DataTable which we just filled (and start loading the previous datable asynchronously) This way UI will always get the current data (without user waiting on UI to refresh or hang)

Comment: Please don't put things like "C# ADO.net" into titles. That's what tags are for on [SO].

Comment: Are you using the AsyncMethodCaller with an IAsyncResult?

Comment: @James, I am using normal Delegate and call beginInvoke on it. which eventually fill the datatable. In the callback method, I bind that data to datagrid.

Comment: Please post some code so we can see how you're doing it. On a side note, why are you doing this asynchronously? The way you're describing it, it sounds like it should be a synchronous operation. I don't see what the gain is since you still have to wait for the thead to complete before you can bind the results to the grid.

Comment: @James, if the primary (UI) thread is doing the work of filling the data, that means the UI will be unresponsive, which is considered very sloppy.

Comment: @James Doing a lengthy database operation on the UI thread is a good way to lock up the UI.

Comment: @James please see UPDATE in the post.

Comment: I understand all of that, but doesn't the primary thread need to wait anyway since it can't bind the results to the grid or post the page until the second thread has finished? I understand that doing this allows you to load the rest of the UI, but it seems like it could be overkill in a lot of situations. I can see doing something like this in cases when, for example, you're filling a dataset, and want to execute several queries asynchronously, but it doesn't seem like there's a big performance gain in this situation. Maybe I'm wrong though...

Comment: @James, not to get lost in the details, I posted the question to know if there is a way I can cancel existing (executing) Adapter.fill() and start another one.

Comment: @karephul: You need to post some code. You've stated how you're doing it, but I think it will be difficult for anyone to answer without seeing some code.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a SqlCommand to adapter constructor and invoke a Cancel method on it.
There is a raw template :

```
class Model 
{
    private SqlCommand loadUserCommand;
    private DataTable userData;

    public void LoadUser(string userId) 
    {
        loadUserCommand = GetUserLoadCommandForUserID(userId);
        userData = new DataTable("userData");
        using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(loadUserCommand)) 
        {
            adapter.Fill(userData);
        }
    }

    public void AbortLoadUser()
    {
        if (loadUserCommand!= null)
            loadUserCommand.Cancel();
    }


    private SqlCommand GetUserLoadCommandForUserID(string userId)
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection("...");
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing calls AbortLoadUser is your template. How do you envisage that being called?

Comment: LoadUser and AbortLoadUser are public methods of a Model class and can be called from UI, for example from button click event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no facility to **safely** cancel `DataAdapter.Fill()`.

To work around this, one option would be to implement a mechanism that can cause these unwanted fills to be ignored and so not reflected in the UI. I would recommend incrementing a counter at the beginning of an async operation and passing that state to your asyn action. Your async action can then check its counter value against the current counter when it finishes. If the counters are not equal, then do not update the UI.

If you see a pattern where the user rapidly clicks between users and lots of requests get discarded, then implement a timer mechanism whereby you only retrieve data if the user stays on the selection for a minimum amount of time.

Comment: The real problem is, if I try to call adapter.fill(query, datatable) again with a differnt query when there is anotherone executing, it throws, "IllegalOperationException". I think DataAdapter should have exposed an API to check the status, based upon that client should take suitable action.

Comment: I am currently doing the same thing, maintaining a flag myself (executing) and based upon that I accomodate the requests. But if fill takes long time, then I am just waiting for the fill which I don't need anyways.

Comment: @karephul You should use a new DataAdapter for each call. You don't need to wait for ignored fills then.

Comment: I am not sure if creating new DataAdapter is so cheap that a new one can be instantiated for every fill()

Comment: Creating the adapter is cheap, it's running the query which is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using CancellationToken:

```cs
SqlCommand command = ...;
using var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
var userData = new DataTable("userData");
var cancelRegistration = myCancellationToken.Register(() => command.Cancel());
try
{
    adapter.Fill(userData);
}
finally
{
    cancelRegistration.Unregister();
}
```

You can now cancel your CancellationToken from somewhere else to cancel the Fill...